# Sync Bookmarks, passwords in Firefox using Firefox Sync

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

I have used **Firefox Sync** and successfully setup sync on two devices. It is working fine. The only issue I am seeing is that Bookmarks don't sync up automatically. I need to click on

> **Tools -> Sync Now**

After clicking on above mentioned button, I immediately see the effect on bookmarks.

Is there any configuration using which Firefox sync can run automatically ?

Comment: Any changes made on any devices with a Firefox Sync account will automatically update. However this doesn't always happen instantaneously. If it's not happening after about an hour, then you are hitting a different issue.

Comment: @Josiah Oh..I didn't wait for one hour actually. May be syncing process gets initiated after some time. Thanks